# Finding volume of revolution for $y=x^{2}+2$ about $y=-2$ on the interval $[0,2]$

Tags: calculus, solid-of-revolution

Finding the volume obtained of a curve after revolving it around $y=-2$, using Mathematica gives
$$V=\pi \int_{0}^{2} \left(4+x^{2} \right)^{2}dx=\dfrac{896 \pi }{15}$$
However, in the solution manual it is,
$$R=x^{2}+2-(-2)=x^{2}+4$$
$$r=0-(-2)=2$$
$$V=\pi \int_{0}^{2} \left[(x^{2}+4)^{2} -2^{2} \right]dx=\dfrac{776\pi}{15}$$

I don't understand why did Mathematica take only the outer radius? I am confused now to which one is correct.

Comment: You have substracted whole cylinder with radius 2 and hight 2. Why?

Comment: @greedoid I am sorry, I forgot to add that it is revolved around $y=-2$.

Comment: Could you post the command you passed to Mathematica ?

Comment: @Claude Leibovici I used this calculator  http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=rotate+y%3Dx%5E2%2B2%2C+0<x<2+about+the+line+y%3D-2

Answer (score 1):

Your radius is $y$, since you are rotating around the $x$-axis (y=0), right?. It is sufficient to compute 
\begin{eqnarray}
V &=& \pi \int_0^2 y(x)^2 \,dx \\
&=& \pi \int_0^2 (x^2+2)^2 \,dx \\
&=& \pi \left(\frac{1}{5}2^5 + \frac{2}{3}2^3 + 2 \cdot2\right)\\
&=& \pi \frac{96 + 90 + 60}{15} \\
&=& \pi \frac{246}{15} \\
\end{eqnarray}
Am I understanding you correctly?

**Edit:**

If it revolves about the line $y=-2$, you need to add the volume of the additionally created cylinder with radius $r = 2$ and height $h = 4$ ($V_C = \pi r^2h = 16 \pi$). This yields a total volume of 
\begin{eqnarray}
V_{tot}&=& \pi\left(\frac{246}{15}+16\right) = \pi\left(\frac{246+240}{15}\right) =\pi\frac{486}{15}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: I am actually rotating around $y=-2$, not the $x$-axis, I would usually solve it as the book, using washers, but when trying in Mathematica it gave me a totally different answer. It discarded the inner radius... and I am now confused as to which solution is correct (the solution manual or mathematica).

Comment: why does it say $y=0$ in the title?

Comment: I meant the region between $y=x^{2}+2$ and $y=0$, I know however it is not necessary to write $y=0$, but it is revolved around the line $y=-2$ as I mentioned under the question.

Comment: I edited the question :)